# Unity, Firebase and Cross Platform

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, tizen

I found on firebase docs that I can implement the server even in Unity. Is it possible to code the server services only once, so without splitting the app in Android and iOS version? I haven't found the Tizen SDK, can I use firebase with it?

Is there a good and secure server SDK to use for Tizen, Android and iOS?

(I have a pc)

Comment: *firebaser here* There is no way to run your code on Firebase's servers (yet). Keep an eye out for announcements though. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your bad news :(